# Android change bitmap transparency on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I want to be able to slowly make a bitmap image more and more transparent on my canvas.

Currently I am drawing the .png file (stored in drawables) like this:

```
  //I setup the Bitmap in my constructor.
  heartSymb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.heartsymbol);

  //This is in on draw.
  canvas.drawBitmap(heartSymb,0,0,null);
```

How would I be able to slowly change the bitmap's transparency until it becomes fully transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Paint` object to modify the alpha of the bitmap to be drawn:

```
Paint alphaPaint = new Paint();
alphaPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
canvas.drawBitmap(heartSymb, 0, 0, alphaPaint);
```

Then you just have to modify `alpha` value and perform update periodically, maybe by using a Handler.